# How to use a single component in multiple places?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In React, one creates components that can be used as needed almost like HTML components.  However I have different use cases for my components, and they are used in different areas of the UI.

Consequently, I need different CSS to position the component.

For example, if I have

`Component.jsx` and `Component.css`, but I want to use Component.jsx in different places, with different CSS, what is the design pattern or strategy I should use to do this?

For example,

```
.medd_link {
  margin-top:3px;
  float: right;
}
```

I need to be

```
.medd_link{
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
```

in a different use case.

Comment: You can pass different styles to the component using props

Comment: A component shouldn't need to know where it is in a parent. The best practice would be to control positioning css in the parent component - so move `component.css` to `parent-component.css` and use those styles in `ParentComponent.jsx`.

Comment: I think you're overthinking it. If you need your component to be "flexible" you should provide that flexibility through the props. Imagine a simple button - you set it's height, width, color, etc. If it's not enough maybe you're trying to do something unusual?

Answer (score 2):

> what is the design pattern or strategy I should use to do this?

It's called [Specialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#specialization).

You can create a generic component which is used by specialized components.
The specialized components will have its own style.

```js
function Component(props) {
  const { style, text } = props;
  return (
    <div style={{...style}}>
      {text}
    </div>
  );
}

Component.defaultProps = {
  style: {
    marginTop: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
  }
}

// Specialized Component
function ComponentA(props) {
  const style = {
    width: "20px",
    height: "20px",
    position: "absolute",
    marginTop: "10px",
    backgroundColor: "green"
  };

  return (
    <Component style={style} text="A" />
  );
}

// Another Specialized Component
function ComponentB(props) {
  const style = {
    width: "20px",
    height: "20px",
    position: "absolute",
    marginLeft: "50px",
    backgroundColor: "red",
  };

  return (
    <Component style={style} text="B" />
  );
}

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentA />
      <ComponentB />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you can set a css class using the className prop. For example:

```
.position_one {
  margin-top:3px;
  float: right;
}

.position_two{
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

<YourComponent className="position_one" />
<YourComponent className="position_two" />
```